# Property 'ELEMENT_DATA' is used before its initialization. - in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I searched in google and StackOverflow about this error but I am not able to fix this error can anyone help me.

[image]

Comment: please write the relevant text of the image in the question, to make sure it'll be easier to find for the next dev with the same question

Answer (score 0):

you are using the variable without assigning a value to it, the error message is very clear.
In your case ELEMENT_DATA need to have a value before you can use it within your constructor

```
ELEMENT_DATA: Souls[] = [];
```